# Is there a more efficient way to normalize the number of characters of a field?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column field in the below situation:

| LENGTH(FIELD_NAME) | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 1271 |
| 7 | 81 |
| 5 | 33 |
| 3 | 125 |
| 1 | 12 |

I want to normalize this field so that all rows contain 6 digits. The requirements is to go from right to left and add leading zeros if necessary.

The solution I came up with is as follows:

```
CASE
    WHEN LENGTH(FIELD_NAME) < 6 THEN LPAD(FIELD_NAME, 6, '0')
    WHEN LENGTH(FIELD_NAME) > 6 THEN SUBSTR(FIELD_NAME, -6)
    ELSE FIELD_NAME
END
```

**Is there a more efficient (better) way to achieve the same result?**

Comment: So far so good!

Comment: I don't think the case expression is necessary (unless substr() throws an error). You can just substring and left-pad directly: `LPAD(SUBSTR(FIELD_NAME, -6), 6, '0') as FIELD_NAME`

Comment: How do you mean "more efficient" or "better"? In what way? Less code? Faster execution time?

Comment: @JNevill I believe that using the SUBSTR function on rows with less than 6 characters will output NULL. Does this not happen to you? Thank you!

Comment: @AndyLester faster execution time since I'm dealing with a lot of data :)

Comment: If you have a query that is performing poorly, it's not likely that it's because of string manipulation. Most query problems are because of incorrect or inadequate indexing, or because the query is doing more work than it needs to. The amount of time it takes Oracle to do some fiddling with strings is dwarfed by the amount of time it takes to read data from disk.  So, if you have a slow query and you want to speed it up, make a new question and ask us to help optimize it. Tag it with [query-optimization].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepend six zeroes and then take the sub-string of the last 6 characters:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR('000000' || value, -6) as short_field_name
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123456' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1234567' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12345678' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123456789' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | SHORT_FIELD_NAME |
> | --- |
> | 000123 |
> | 001234 |
> | 012345 |
> | 123456 |
> | 234567 |
> | 345678 |
> | 456789 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3d39e508d16eea35b1ff5a0efdc892f3)*

Comment: Such an easy and clean way to do it! Thank you :D